# How to shorten a math command in Latex

Tags: macros, math-operators

I am trying to shorten the adaptable bracket size `left[` into `\l[` (same for `\right]`).

I have tried both:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\l[}{\left[}
\DeclareMathOperator{\r]}{\right]}
```

and:

```
\newcommand{\l[}{\left[}
\newcommand{\r]}{\right]}
```

Any idea?

Comment: You cannot define a macro containing letters as well as `[` or `]`. You could define macros `\l` and `\r` but they already exist. Overwriting them is possible but no good idea.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Any ideas?

Instead of defining shortcuts for `\left[` and `\right]` directly, I suggest you pursue an indirect approach: load the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package -- a superset of the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package -- and run

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\br}{[}{]}
```

This defines two macros: `\br`, which encases its argument with basic-size square brackets, and `\br*`, which auto-sizes the square brackets.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\br}{[}{]}

\begin{document}
\[
\br{a} \quad \br*{\frac{u}{v}} \quad \br*{\int_0^1\! h(x)\,dx}
\]
\end{document}
```